# Having confusion in using PatIndex in Linq to Sql ? returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities

i am trying to get tribe id from query matching by its tribe name,

```
  var Rid = db.Regions.Where(p => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%" + Search + "%", p.RegionName) > 0).Select(p=>p.RegionId);
```

It gets id as i can check it is like [0]=1 i am trying to get it in int variable in this way,

```
                string id = Rid.ToString();
```

but it showing long string in id variable not id itself.

Now i am trying to get query result down there according to regionId but it is not showing any result.

```
  var tribes = db.Tribes.Include(t => t.City).Include(t => t.Region).Where(p => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("" + id + "", p.RegionId.ToString())>0);
```

I am doing it this way because my model do not have  regionid so i have to do it like above senario.

Hopes for your help

Comment: Why would you use PatIndex if you're not using any of the special pattern characters?

Comment: Your `patindex` can be replaced with a simple `like`, or translated to c# with `string.Contains`...